# Windows phone 8.1 Face Detection C#

Tags: c#, opencv, windows-phone-8.1, emgucv, lbph-algorithm

I am currently working on my project for Windows Phone 8.1 Face Detection in C#. I have already finished face detection but now I have a serious problem with Face Tracking and extraction of face signs from image.  I would like to use for this LBP method, but LBP method in library OpenCV and EmguCV is still not supported for windows phone 8.1 . I also tried to use  Face SDK Beta from Microsoft, but it is supported only for windows phone 7. Has anybody have some experience with some libraries or methods in windows phone 8.1 in C# .

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. Microsoft released support for Windows Phone OpenCV library :  [here](http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/08/20/opencv-support-for-windows-universal-apps-now-available-on-github/) and

[here](http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/03/20/easily-build-opencv-powered-apps-for-windows-store/)